# LoadLibrary failed with error 0, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: c, winapi, loadlibrary

`LoadLibrary` returns handle 0, but `GetLastError()` also returns 0. Ideas?
One thing to note is this piece of code used to work fine, I did not alter anything. I have just cloned project's repository into another folder, rebuilt it there and got a problem.

Comment: check whether you're calling `LoadLibrary` from `DllMain`

Comment: Accidentally destroying the thread's last error value is a very common bug.  Call GetLastError() immediately after the if() statement.  Post code.

Comment: @HansPassant: you're right, id didn't occur to me that my loggers calls API function that overwrites last error. Please make this an answer :)